# How to build tensorflow from sources by changing cpu optimization flags in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, conda, tensorflow2.0

While importing tensorflow i was getting error,

```
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime
```

I asked tensorflow about this question but it doesnot have solution rather than by use alternatives like
colab.

I found one answer not very much in detail that
 ***build tf from sources by changing cpu optimization flags***
I didnt find answer of it.so,

---

> *How do i build it from sources changing cpu optimization flags?*

---

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you should do..

1. Remove Ancaonda or whatever you use as an editor, and make clear
   installation.
2. Download the compatible .whl file from here [a
   link](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) . I
   downloaded tensorflow 1.11.0 from py37/cpu/sse2/...
3. Install compatible keras-application. I used `pip install Keras-Applications==1.0.5`
4. Install compatible keras-preprocessing. I used `pip install Keras-Preprocessing == 1.0.3`

That's worked for me.

Comment: I've already found 2.0.0 version which is precompiled, no need to use 1.x version in my cpu which dont support avx instrction.